# StageText. How to store user input in a variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a a stageText object which is working on my phone. I can type into the field and it displays the text. How do I capture the input text and store it in a variable for later use? Thank you.

```
var qatAccessCode:StageText = new StageText();
qatAccessCode.softKeyboardType = SoftKeyboardType.NUMBER;
qatAccessCode.restrict = "0-9";
qatAccessCode.returnKeyLabel = ReturnKeyLabel.GO;
qatAccessCode.stage = this.stage;
qatAccessCode.viewPort = new Rectangle(225, 765, 200, 35 );
```

Answer (score 2):

you make a one String variable. and stageText add Change Event. and stored stageText property `text` when occur event. later use a String variable.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.text.ReturnKeyLabel;
import flash.text.SoftKeyboardType;
import flash.text.StageText;
import flash.events.Event;

var str:String;
var stageText:StageText = new StageText();
stageText.softKeyboardType = SoftKeyboardType.NUMBER;
stageText.restrict = "0-9";
stageText.returnKeyLabel = ReturnKeyLabel.GO;

stageText.stage = this.stage;
stageText.viewPort = new Rectangle(10, 10, 300, 40 );
stageText.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onChange);
function onChange(e:Event):void
{
    str = stageText.text;

    trace(str);
}
```

Comment: Awesome and thx! How can the var "str" that has the stored numbers, be available outside of the function so I can use it elsewhere?

Comment: you'll possible anywhere. because `str` variable is global. so you can any function any line access avaiiable.

Comment: I tried this in various ways and when I move trace(str); outside of the onChange function it returns "null." And I haven't been able to use "str" as a global variable. It works as a normal function but not as an Event Listener function. Is this because the onChange function returns void?